# How can I create hashmap of hashmap in java?

Tags: java, text-mining, information-retrieval

I have some documents. For example 1000 documents. Each document has some words. 
for example

Doc 1 : Hello I am from Earth

Doc 2 : Hello I am from Mars Hello how

Doc 2 : Earth Mars sun

output should be like this

[Hello: doc1-1, doc2-2 doc3-0][I: doc1-1,doc2-1, doc3-0].....

like it needs to store the individual word and its frequency associated with documents.

I guess it requires mapping. But I dont know how to do mapping ?
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you need a `HashMap` of `Hashmap's`.  Really, all you need is a `Map` where the key is a `String`, and the `Value` is a `Collection`.  You could create this abstraction yourself, or you can use something like google [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) [MultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Or, instead of writing an query doc from scratch, you can use something like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) and skip writing all of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String[] files = { "doc1", "doc2", "doc3" };
int size = files.length;
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    Path path = Paths.get(files[i]);
    Map<String, Long> count = Files.readAllLines(path).stream()
        .flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s")))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
    for (Entry<String, Long> e : count.entrySet()) {
        Map<String, Long> m = result.get(e.getKey());
        if (m == null)
            result.put(e.getKey(), m = new TreeMap<>());
        m.put(files[i], e.getValue());
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    for (Map<String, Long> e : result.values())
        e.compute(files[i], (k, v) -> v == null ? 0 : v);
for (Entry<String, Map<String, Long>> e : result.entrySet())
    System.out.println(e);
```

result:

```
Earth={doc1=1, doc2=0, doc3=1}
how={doc1=0, doc2=1, doc3=0}
Mars={doc1=0, doc2=1, doc3=1}
Hello={doc1=1, doc2=2, doc3=0}
I={doc1=1, doc2=1, doc3=0}
from={doc1=1, doc2=1, doc3=0}
am={doc1=1, doc2=1, doc3=0}
sun={doc1=0, doc2=0, doc3=1}
```

Comment: Well, every document is a text file here
like doc 1 is a text fiile, doc2 is also a text file

how to deal with that?

Comment: Thank you, i have a question, in BufferedReader we specify the path name of the file, but when we use path how it get the path name ?